# amcharts 5 real-time barchart sorting issue

Tags: javascript, amcharts, amcharts5

I'm using amcharts 5 to generate an XY series barchart on a webpage, where the y-axis is a categorical axis of names and the x-axis contains a fractional value representing a rate between 0 and 1. The page loads the chart correctly but when a user attempts to sort based on a different variable (using a drop-down list), the chart will sort the y-axis appropriately but some of the bars (x-axis) will disappear in the chart.

Each data item looks something like this:

`{'name': 'John Doe', 'Rate': .2, 'Exp_rank': 0}`

In the full js code below, when a user selects "Experience" from the drop-down, I change the index of the Y-axis dataItems (in the `sortCategoryAxis` function) to point to the values in 'Exp_rank'.  Using the js code belnames/bars sort but 'Mike' loses his bar.  I've tried several different things such as reversing the order to sort manipulating the ranking so that it's not 0-based, or just using a raw number (instead of a ranking) but they either don't fix the issue or make it worse.  If I pair the data down to less than 7 examples, It seems to work but it gets worse if I add more values.  I want to understand what is it about the sort that's causing the bar loss and how it can be fixed no matter how many data points I display on the bar.

```
<!-- Resources -->
<script src='https://cdn.amcharts.com/lib/5/index.js'></script>
<script src='https://cdn.amcharts.com/lib/5/xy.js'></script>
<script src='https://cdn.amcharts.com/lib/5/themes/Animated.js'></script>
<script src='https://cdn.amcharts.com/lib/5/stock.js'></script>


var barchart;
sortdict = {'id1': 'Exp_rank'};

var root = am5.Root.new("chartdiv");
root.setThemes([
  am5themes_Animated.new(root)
]);

var chart = root.container.children.push(
        am5.Container.new(root, {
            layout: root.gridLayout,
            width: am5.percent(70),
            height: am5.percent(100),
        })
    )
chartstuff = create_bar('Rate','Test Chart');
    
    

// parameters: html_title, category, values
function create_bar(seriesName,title){
    
    var data =[ { name: 'John',
        Rate: 0.005,
        Exp_rank: 0 },
      { name: 'Steve',
        Rate: 0.005,
        Exp_rank: 1 },
      { name: 'Josh',
        Rate: 0.005,
        Exp_rank: 6 },
      { name: 'Greg',
        Rate: 0.005,
        Exp_rank: 7 },
      { name: 'Brandon',
        Rate: 0.0556,
        Exp_rank: 2 },
      { name: 'Dirk',
        Rate: 0.0833,
        Exp_rank: 3 },
      { name: 'Sean',
        Rate: 0.0857,
        Exp_rank: 4 },
      { name: 'Mike',
        Rate: 0.0909,
        Exp_rank: 5 } ]
    

    
    var barchart = chart.children.push(
    am5xy.XYChart.new(
        root, {width: am5.percent(50),
            height: am5.percent(85),
            // paddingTop: 50,
            paddingLeft: 100,
            marginTop: 100,
            
        })
    )

    barchart.children.unshift(am5.Label.new(root, {
        html: title,
        dy: -50,
        fontWeight: 'bold',
        fontSize: 17

        
        }
    ))

    var xAxis = barchart.xAxes.push(
    am5xy.ValueAxis.new(root, {
        renderer: am5xy.AxisRendererX.new(root, {
            opacity: 1,
            numberFormat: "#.00'%'"
        })
    })
    );

    var yAxis = barchart.yAxes.push(
        am5xy.CategoryAxis.new(root, {
            renderer: am5xy.AxisRendererY.new(root, {
                minGridDistance: 12
                
            }),
            categoryField: 'name',
        })
        );
 
    const yAxisRenderer = yAxis.get('renderer');
    const xAxisRenderer = xAxis.get('renderer');
    yAxisRenderer.grid.template.setAll({ disabled: true, visible: false });//hides all
    xAxisRenderer.grid.template.setAll({ disabled: true, visible: false });//hides all

    yAxis.data.setAll(data);
    
    var series = barchart.series.push(am5xy.ColumnSeries.new(root, {
                name: seriesName,
                xAxis: xAxis,
                yAxis: yAxis,
                valueXField: 'Rate',
                categoryYField: 'name',
                fill: am5.color('#e1e1e1'),
                numberFormat : "#.00'%'",
                width: am5.percent(100),
                duration: 5000
            })
        );
            
            
    series.animate({
      key: "fill",
      duration: 5000,
      easing: am5.ease.elastic
    });


   series.dataItems.sort(function(x, y) {
        return x.get("valueX") - y.get("valueX"); // descending
        //return y.get("valueY") - x.get("valueX"); // ascending
        })
    
      
      xAxis.get('renderer').labels.template.set("fontSize", 12);
      // yAxis.get('renderer').labels.template.set("labelFontSize", 12);
      yAxis.get('renderer').labels.template.set("fontSize", 10);

      series.data.setAll(data);
      series.appear();
      series.columns.template.set("interactive", true);
      series.columns.template.set("tooltipText",'Rate: {valueX}');


    let mysorter = am5stock.DropdownListControl.new(root, {
    stockChart: barchart,
     name: "Sorting options",
    items: [{
            id: "id1",
            label: "Experience"
            }]
    })


    var toolbar = am5stock.StockToolbar.new(root, {
    container: document.getElementById("chartcontrols"),
    stockChart: barchart,
    controls: [
        mysorter
    ]
    });
    
    mysorter.events.on("selected",function(ev){
        sortCategoryAxis(series, ev.item.id, xAxis, yAxis);
    })

    return [series, barchart];

}

function getSeriesItem(series,category) {
  for (var i = 0; i < series.dataItems.length; i++) {
    var dataItem = series.dataItems[i];
    if (dataItem.get("categoryY") == category) {;
      return dataItem;
    }
  }
}

function sortCategoryAxis(series,sortType,xAxis, yAxis) {
    
    series.dataItems.sort(function (x, y) {
        return  x.dataContext[sortType] - y.dataContext[sortType]; // descending

      })
    

    am5.array.each(yAxis.dataItems, function (dataItem) {       
        var seriesDataItem = getSeriesItem(series,dataItem.get("category"));
        if (seriesDataItem) {
            var idx = series.dataItems.indexOf(seriesDataItem);
            var n_idx = series.dataItems[idx].dataContext[sortdict[sortType]];
            var deltaPosition = (n_idx - idx) / series.dataItems.length; ;
            dataItem.set("index", n_idx);
            dataItem.set("deltaPosition", -deltaPosition);
            dataItem.animate({
                key: "deltaPosition",
                to: 0,
                duration: 1000,
                easing: am5.ease.out(am5.ease.cubic)
              })
        }
    });

    yAxis.dataItems.sort(function (x, y) {
          return x.get("index") - y.get("index")
        });  
}
```

TIA

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out:  I have a sorting dictionary at the top of the script that takes has an id and associates to a field I want to sort on.  The first part of the sortCategoryAxis function is sorting the x-axis values.  In the script provided I passed the key 'sortType' but didn't give the dictionary.  So the code reads:

`return  x.dataContext[sortType] - y.dataContext[sortType];`

but should be:

`return x.dataContext[sortdict[sortType]] - y.dataContext[sortdict[sortType]]`

That seem to fix the issue.